# Is Testing the DBSCAN clustering algorithm possible? And if yes, how?

Tags: python, testing, machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, dbscan

I want to use the `DBSCAN clustering algorithm` in order to detect outliers in my dataset. As this is an unsupervised learning approach, do I need to split my dataset in training and test data or is testing the `DBSCAN algorithm` just not possible? For outlier detection reasons, should I feed the `DBSCAN model` with my entire dataset?

In case testing `DBSCAN` is possible, can you suggest ways in doing that with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to split your data into test and train. However, you should have a sample of labelled data from your original data if you wish to evaluate your model. There are other unsupervised ways as well, but they compare which clustering method is performing better relative to other methods that you try (algorithms or different hyperparameters).

I would suggest reading - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html
The section 2.3.10 shows the various methods for evaluation of your clustering models, and the sklearn API needed to implement them.

You can choose which one suits your requirement best based on your problem statement.

Comment: Thanks! The link with the overview of clustering algorithms is super useful! Will have a deeper look into the evaluation methods suggested.

Answer (score 1):

For outlier detection, use an actual **outlier detection algorithm** instead of DBSCAN.

Noise as detected by DBSCAN is ***not* the same as outliers**. For examples if you data is all uniform random data, this ought to be considered "noise", but none of them will be outliers. All the data is normal noise.

Comment: And which **outlier detection algorithm** would you suggest? Lots of sources suggest for more-dimensional data DBSCAN and Isolation Forest for detecting outliers...

Comment: I'm not a fan of isolation forests. If you want something similar to DBSCAN, use for example LOF or LOOP by the same group.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add another important point here:

You cannot test unsupervised learning methods. The main idea from unsupervised learning methods is to define a non-predefiend target.

Supervised learning methods in machine learning --> train/test or train/dev/test split

unsupervised learning --> no split

Depending on your dataset for outliers there are also other statistical methods to identify outliers:

quantilies

z-score

Comment: Thanks! Yes, so basically unsupervised learning models can not be tested, but evaluated, e.g. how well clusters are defined.

Comment: I have a twodimensional feature space, so I chose to detect outliers with DBSCAN. In one-dimensional cases I have calculated Zscores.

Comment: for two dimensional a scatter plot is also interessting

Comment: Already done that :) But in the scatter plot there were some areas were it was not easy to visually identify the outliers